# Add and / Or Updated Based on same table

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+--------+------+------------+
| ITEMNO | UNIT | CONVERSION |
+--------+------+------------+
| 123    | CTN  | 50         |
+--------+------+------------+
| 456    | CTN  | 300        |
+--------+------+------------+
| 789    | CTN  | 200        |
+--------+------+------------+
```

What i would like is to have a query that

A) Adds the same ITEMNO with a "UNIT" of "CT" and the same CONVERSION as "CTN"

B) If the ITEMNO already has a "UNIT" of "CT" update it with the same CONVERSION as "CTN"

There are more than these two "UNIT" but these are the only ones i need to play with.

tried this as an update but that didnt work :(

```
update ICUNIT 
set ICUNIT.CONVERSION  = (
select CONVERSION from ICUNIT
where UNIT = 'CTN')
from ICUNIT
where UNIT = 'CT'
```

hope someone can help !!

Comment: Please don't add an answer to the question. Also please read both [this article](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/08/what-to-avoid-if-you-want-to-use-merge/) and [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) in full before you decide on `MERGE` - I describe a better `UPSERT` pattern [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern). If you're going to use `MERGE` anyway please always use `HOLDLOCK` on the target.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, I recommend steering clear of `MERGE`. A lot of background in these articles:

- [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- ["UPSERT" Race Condition With MERGE](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2009/01/31/upsert-race-condition-with-merge/)
- [Mythbusting: Concurrent Update/Insert Solutions](https://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/)
- [Be Careful with the Merge Statement](https://michaeljswart.com/2012/08/be-careful-with-the-merge-statement/)
- [What To Avoid If You Want To Use MERGE](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/08/what-to-avoid-if-you-want-to-use-merge/)

You need to perform both an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE`. Those are two operations that need to happen inside a protected transaction, even if you use syntactic sugar like `MERGE` that makes it *seem* like one operation.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE trg WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) 
  SET trg.CONVERSION = src.CONVERSION,
    ... other columns you want to match ...
FROM dbo.ICUNIT AS src
INNER JOIN dbo.ICUNIT AS trg
  ON src.ITEMNO = trg.ITEMNO
  WHERE src.CONVERSION = 'CTN'
    AND trg.CONVERSION = 'CT';

INSERT dbo.ICUNIT(ITEMNO, CONVERSION, ... other columns ...)
  SELECT ITEMNO, CONVERSION = 'CT', ... other columns ...
    FROM dbo.ICUNIT AS src
    WHERE src.CONVERSION = 'CTN'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ICUNIT AS trg
        WHERE trg.CONVERSION = 'CT' AND trg.ITEMNO = src.ITEMNO);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

It's a few more characters than `MERGE` but avoids all of its inherent problems (I explain more in [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)). If you insist on using `MERGE`, please, please, please apply `HOLDLOCK` to the target table - if you don't, that's when the fact that it is multiple operations under the covers really starts to unravel.

Anyway, it seems like an odd goal... why have two rows if you want both to always match on all the columns other than `CONVERSION`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a `MERGE`

```sql
WITH
  t AS (SELECT * FROM ICUNIT WHERE CONVERSION = 'CT' ),
  s AS (SELECT * FROM ICUNIT WHERE CONVERSION = 'CTN')
MERGE t WITH (HOLDLOCK)
USING s
ON t.ITEMNO = s.ITEMNO
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    CONVERSION = s.CONVERSION,
    AUDTDATE = s.AUDTDATE,
    AUDTTIME = s.AUDTTIME,
    AUDTUSER = s.AUDTUSER,
    AUDTORG = s.AUDTORG
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
  (ITEMNO, UNIT, CONVERSION,AUDTDATE,AUDTTIME,AUDTUSER,AUDTORG)
  VALUES
  (s.ITEMNO, 'CT', s.CONVERSION,s.AUDTDATE,s.AUDTTIME,s.AUDTUSER,s.AUDTORG);
```

Comment: i have added to your code as i just realised some of the values are required, are you able to take a look and see if it makes sense :)?

Comment: i have added some more field in the following section "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ITEMNO, UNIT, CONVERSION) if you look at my main question i believe i am pulling from the original CTN section just want to make sure its correct

Comment: No, you probably want to add the other fields to the `UPDATE` section also (depends exactly what result you'd like)

Comment: ahhh smart !!, didnt think of that !

looks good thanks so much !!!